# How to assign my integer value to CMTime iOS Sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios, avassetwriter

i want to assign my int value to CMTime type variable

i want this to code like:

```
CMTime frameTime;
if (i == 0 && i == 1) {
    frameTime = 0;//CMTimeMake(value, preferredTimeScale);
}
else if(i == 2) {
    frameTime = 2;
}
else {
    frameTime = 3;
}

append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer 
                  withPresentationTime:frameTime];
```

instead of:

```
int64_t value = 10000;
int32_t preferredTimeScale = 600;
frameTime = CMTimeMake(value, preferredTimeScale);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. CMTime is a struct. You're going to have to use a constructor of some kind with it, not just assigning an integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure if this helps you but i am using CMTime like this :

```
float seeking = songDuration*[slider value];
CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake(seeking, 1);
[mainDelegate.theAudio seekToTime:seekingCM]; //mainDelegate.theAudio is avplayer
```

the code above just creates the CMTime for me for the exact time that i want to go on the audio and on the slider..

i hope this is what you are looking for..

Comment: thanks for you reply...this is something near to my requirement...here i have one question is: i saved my ".mov" file in my photo library...how to find the movie currentplaying time...

Comment: you can the avplayeritem's current time , you can check the currentplaying time there .. that's what i am doing right now :))